# how can i access a web page domain in java script without adding java script file to the html file scripts?

Tags: javascript

I'm a medium-level programmer in javascript and I was anxious about how to have access to the domain of a web page without adding the file into the page script. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you include a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve? Your question is very vague.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean how to get the current page domain you can use `window.location.hostname`

If you don't want to "add a JavaScript file to the HTML file", the only alternative is to embed the JavaScript code into the HTML code (which I don't recommend) by using `<script>` tags.

```html
<script>
    console.log(window.location.hostname);
</script>
```